# Не могу назначить StandardGestures динамически

Tags: android, c++, radstudio, firemonkey, gestures

```
nb= new TButton(Form1);
nb->Parent = Form1;
nb->Touch->GestureManager= GestureManager1;
nb->Touch->StandardGestures=TStandardGestures::sgLeft;//так попробовал

nb->Touch->StandardGestures=TStandardGestures<<sgLeft;//так попробовал
```

В чем ошибка? не понимаю синтаксиса.

Comment: Какая ошибка???

Comment: вот такая "no member named 'sgLeft' in 'System::Set<Fmx::Types::TStandardGesture, 1, 34>'"